# "Resolving 'cors' Type Error after NestJs Apollo Update to Server v4: Seeking Guidance"

Tags: typescript, express, graphql, nestjs, apollo

I recently updated my NestJs-Apollo project and now I'm encountering an error stating that 'cors' is not present in the type 'Omit'. Upon research, I found that this is related to the update to Apollo Server v4 and that now CORS options should be used for the Express server.

Here is my current code snippet:

```
// ... other imports

@Module({
  imports: [
    GraphQLModule.forRoot<ApolloGatewayDriverConfig>({
      driver: ApolloGatewayDriver,
      server: {
        cors: true, // This is causing an error
      },
      // ... other configuration options
    }),
  ],
})
export class MyAppComponent {}
```

How can I resolve this error and correctly configure CORS options for the Express server?

Thanks in advance for your assistance!

```
import { Module } from '@nestjs/common';
import { GraphQLModule } from '@nestjs/graphql';
import { ApolloGatewayDriver, ApolloGatewayDriverConfig } from '@nestjs/apollo';

@Module({
  imports: [
    GraphQLModule.forRoot<ApolloGatewayDriverConfig>({
      driver: ApolloGatewayDriver,
      server: {
        cors: {
          credentials: true,
          origin: true,
        },
      },
      // Other configuration options
    }),
  ],
})
export class YourAppModule {}
```